# Are UniqueIdentifier keys supported by Vici CoolStorage for MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uniqueidentifier, coolstorage

A sqlite table declared like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Note(Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Title TEXT)
```

is correctly read by Vici CoolStorage on Windows, but on MonoTouch, the following exception is thrown:

``` [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at Vici.CoolStorage.CSDataProviderSQLite.GetSchemaColumns (System.String tableName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Vici.CoolStorage.CSSchema.CreateColumns () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Vici.CoolStorage.CSSchema..ctor (System.Type objType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Vici.CoolStorage.CSSchema.Get (System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Vici.CoolStorage.CSList``1[Store.CoolStorage.Note]..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 ```

It looks like the code that detects the data type of a column based on the type ID does not handle the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type in Vici's CSDataProviderSqlite for MonoTouch:

From CSSqliteConnection.GetSchema:

```
switch (dbType) 
{
    case "TEXT": dataType = typeof(string); break;
    case "VARCHAR": dataType = typeof(string); break;
    case "INTEGER": dataType = typeof(int); break;
    case "BOOL": dataType = typeof(bool); break;
    case "DOUBLE": dataType = typeof(double); break;
    case "FLOAT": dataType = typeof(double); break;
    case "REAL": dataType = typeof(double); break;
    case "CHAR": dataType = typeof(string); break;
    case "BLOB": dataType = typeof(byte[]); break;
    case "NUMERIC": dataType = typeof(decimal); break;
    case "DATETIME": dataType = typeof(DateTime); break;
}
```

There isn't an handler for UNIQUEIDENTIFIER here. Is this a bug in Vici CoolStorage?

Comment: It's not a bug, but it's not explicitly supported

Comment: @Philippe, is there a workaround for this exception in MonoTouch? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just modify Vici, since it looks like you have access to the source code:

```
switch (dbType) 
{
    case "TEXT": dataType = typeof(string); break;
    case "VARCHAR": dataType = typeof(string); break;
    case "INTEGER": dataType = typeof(int); break;
    case "BOOL": dataType = typeof(bool); break;
    case "DOUBLE": dataType = typeof(double); break;
    case "FLOAT": dataType = typeof(double); break;
    case "REAL": dataType = typeof(double); break;
    case "CHAR": dataType = typeof(string); break;
    case "BLOB": dataType = typeof(byte[]); break;
    case "NUMERIC": dataType = typeof(decimal); break;
    case "DATETIME": dataType = typeof(DateTime); break;
    case "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER": dataType = typeof(Guid); break;
}
```

If there is more required beyond that, you will have to try. Unless there is no try. Use the source, Luke.

Comment: Yes, that is what I already did, but thanks Yoda :) for confirming that this is the right thing to do.